# V4L2 invalid argument for the ioctl of DQBUF

Tags: c, embedded, v4l2

I came across a V4L2 problem.Below is the code.

```
v4l2_buffer queue_buf;
CLEAR(queue_buf);

queue_buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
queue_buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

if(-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &queue_buf))
{
    perror("dqbuf:");
}
```

When run on **ARM 2440** with **linux 2.6.24**, **arm-linux-gcc 3.4.1**, the error is "dqbuf: invalid argument".But on my PC, it works well.
I don't know why it happened.
thx.

Comment: I just leave it alone.It seems that it Arm2440's problem.

Answer (score 1):

v4l problems are very specific and I had trouble finding help myself, some time ago.

So here are some links where you should be searching for help:

- [Hans de Goede](http://people.atrpms.net/~hdegoede/) and [his blog](http://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/). He is the programmer of the libv4l2 user space library
- [v4l wiki: developer section](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Developer_Section)
- [v4l wiki: contact infos](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Other_Sources_of_Info). I suggest you mail to the linux-media mailinglist.

I hope this helps.

regards.